# MySQLi installation PHP 5.5.8 Windows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I use `phpinfo()`, I don't see a table starting with MySQLi. I do see a table for mysqlnd, but I'm not sure what that is. However, when I go to command line and type `php -m` mysqli is there. `mysqli_connect()` fails, so it appears that its not actually installed.

MySQL 5.6 is installed. My PHP version is 5.5.8 on Apache 2.4.7 for Windows.

PHP is installed in C:\php, `extension_dir = "ext"`, enabled `php_mysql.dll` and `php_mysqli.dll`, so I'm not sure why this doesn't work. Have I missed a step somewhere?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. As I see, it doesn't load when the path is relative. Try with absolute path, e.g.

```
extension_dir="C:/php/ext"
```

It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

The absolute path is needed apache and php are installed in different drives! And also, you'll need to restart apache server after making changes to php.ini.